# What is partial derivatives? Just differentiate the explicit variables is enough?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

From Euler-Lagrange equation, $$L=L(q(t),\dot q(t),t)$$$$\cfrac{dL}{dt}=\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial q}\cfrac{dq}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\cfrac{d\dot q}{dt}+\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial t}$$
So, from pure mathematics perspective, it is just saying that for a function $$f=f(x,y,t)=x+y$$$$x=x(t)=2t$$$$y=y(t)=3t^2$$$$\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0\quad!!!$$
If this is really true, how about that
$$f=f(x,y)=x+y$$$$x=x(t)=2t$$$$y=y(t)=3t^2$$$$\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=?$$
Also how about that, $$f=f(x,y)=x+y$$$$x=x(s)=2s$$$$y=y(t)=3t^2$$$$\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=?$$

Comment: The concept you are looking for is the "multivariable chain rule".

Comment: It is confusing notation but firmly embedded in variational calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is the [multivariable chain rule](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx).

In your first example, the symbol $t$ takes on two distinct meanings: one as a independent variable, and another as an identity function of that independent variable. This is an abuse of notation, but a very common one. It's conceptually helpful to re-write the example as $f=f(x,y,z)$ where $x(t)=2t$, $y(t)=3t^2$, and $z(t)=t$. From here applying the chain rule is straight-forward, but since this is the most notationally complex of the examples you've given, I'll discuss it last.

In your second example, you have a function $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, $f=f(\vec {x})$, where $\vec x: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ is itself a function of $t$. By the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \nabla f \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = (1)(2)+ (1)(6t) = 3+6t
$$

Likewise, in the third case, we have $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, $f=f(\vec {x})$ where $\vec x: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is a function of both $s$ and $t$. By the same principal,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = (1)(0) + (1)(6t) = 6t.
$$

Returning to the first example, we have a function $f: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$, $f=f(\vec x)$, where $\vec x: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$ is given by
$$
\vec x(t) = \langle x(t), \,y(t), \,z(t)\rangle = \langle 2t, \,3t^2, \, t \rangle.
$$
Applying the chain rule to this case gives us
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = (1)(2) + (1)(6t) + (0)(1) = 3 + 6t.
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how about you apply this chain rule to the case of $$f=f(x,y,t)$$

Comment: @KongyiuchongKong Strictly speaking, that function as written is an abuse of notation, which makes it particularly confusing to rationalize. It may be helpful to re-write it as $f=f(x,y,z)$ where $x=x(t)=2t$, $y=y(t)=3t^2$, and $z=z(t)=t$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @KongyiuchongKong I have updated my answer to clarify the meaning of your first example.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the expression of the Euler-Lagragane eqution is actually wrong?it should be$$L=L(q(t),\dot q(t),r(t))$$where$$r(t)=t$$

Comment: @KongyiuchongKong I would not say it is wrong per se. Rather, its a mild abuse of notation that some people use to more succinctly express an idea. Always using all of the formal formal boilterplate is quite cumbersome and can be much less enlightening. Its similar to how one might write, say, $x^2- x = O(x^2)$ or $f(\infty) = 1$ or $x^2 = \int 2x \, \mathrm dx$. All of these taken literally don't really make any sense, but we write them anyway since it is readily understood what is meant.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be unclear on the semantics of a partial derivative.

The notation $\frac{\partial f(x,y,t)}{\partial x}$ means to

- temporarily pretend $x$, $y$, and $z$ are independent variables,
- differentiate $f$ with respect to the independent variable $x$, then
- stop pretending that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are independent variables.

We use partial derivatives to find the rates of change of the outputs of the formal function $f$ with respect to each of its inputs independently.  This can be described using any of the phrases

- Differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$ holding all other variables constant.  (The last phrase means that even if $x$, $y$, and/or $z$ are not independent variables, and this lack of independence means that you can not independently vary them, you must perform the calculation as if you could.)
- Differentiate $f$ with respect to its formal argument, $x$.  (Here, we treat $f$ as a machine that takes three arguments and converts them to output.  The clause "$\partial f(x,y,z)$" asserts that the first argument is labelled "$x$".)
- Differentiate $f$ with respect to its first slot.  ("Slot" means an input to the function.  With "$f(x,y,z)$", we announce that $f$ has three slots.)

Notice that this makes *all* of the following meaningless:

- $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$:  Without a prior declaration of the labels of the formal arguments of $f$, there is no way to known which argument of $f$ is to be varied.  So if we had previously announced "$f(a,b,c)$", this is undefined, and if we had previously announced "$f(x,y,z)$", this is defined.  But the notation must be augmented by a prior announcement to resolve this difference.
- $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial t}$:  $t$ is not a formal argument to $f$.
- $\frac{\partial f(x,x,x)}{\partial x}$:  Which formal argument is varying?
- $\frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t),z(t))}{\partial t}$:  $t$ is not a formal argument of $f$.

Note that one may declare $f(x,y,t)$ and then compute $\frac{\partial f(a,b,c)}{\partial a}$.  This is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first formal argument.  That we *really are* talking about positions of formal arguments rather than modelled quantities is sometimes indicated by this notation
$$  f_1 = \partial_1 f = \frac{\partial f(a,b,c)}{\partial a}  \text{,}  $$
all three of which are notation for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first formal argument.

Turning to your examples:

- Your first example has "$f(x,y,t) = x + y$" declares that the formal arguments of $f$ are labelled $x$, $y$, and $t$.  The rate of change of $f(x,y,t) = x+y$ with respect to $t$, the third formal argument, is zero: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$.
- Your second example has "$f(x,y) = x+y$".  Since $f$ is not declared to have a formal parameter $t$, the expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is undefined; it does not have a value.
- Your third example has the same deficiency as the second: $t$ is not a formal argument of $f$, so $f$ does not have a partial derivative with respect to $t$.

Finally, it can be useful to write in words what your first, total derivative, expression means:

- $\cfrac{dL}{dt}$ is the total derivative of $L(q(t),\dot q(t),t)$ with respect to the independent variable $t$.  It has three contributions:
- $\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial q}\cfrac{dq}{dt}$: the rate of change of $L$ with respect to variation in its first formal argument, times the rate of change of the input to that argument with respect to $t$  (This is an example of the chain rule, where nested rates of change are multiplied.),
- $\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\cfrac{d\dot q}{dt}$: the rate of change of $L$ with respect to variation in its second formal argument, times the rate of change of the input to that argument with respect to $t$, and
- $\cfrac{\partial L}{\partial t}$: the rate of change of $L$ with respect to variation in its third formal argument, which is already bound to the variable $t$.

Comment: Thank you so much~ i read your answer 3 times, it helps a lot